# printing first 10 lines of my feed

Tags: python, json, feed

```
import json 

with open('output.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:  
   output = json.loads(json_file.read())
feeds = []
for feed in output ['posts']:
   feeds.append (feed)
print (feeds[1]['title'])
```

I am trying to print only the first 10 lines of my data. I tried 'enumerate' and other codes but none of them seem to work. Any ideas of how i can get only the first 10 titles of my output?

Comment: `in output ['posts'][:10]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[:10]` as a slice will get you up to the first 10 elements:

```
import json

with open('output.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:  
    output = json.loads(json_file.read())
feeds = []
for feed in output ['posts'][:10]: #   <---- Change on this line
    feeds.append (feed)
print (feeds[1]['title'])
```

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the response. The code you suggested still only prints the first line as indicated by feeds [1]. What should i do if i want the first 10 lines of the data?

Comment: Hi i tried the following and it worked:     
    feeds = []for feed in output ['posts'][:10]:
    print (str(feed['title']))
    feeds.append (feed)